# How can I make this fixed nav stop flashing?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a fixed nav bar that fades out when scrolling down the page and reappears when scrolling up the page which all works fine but I've noticed if I do this very quickly with short movement say 20 times. It doesn't have time to do it and seems to store the count and will then continue to flash for that amount of times. How can I stop this?

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var previousScroll = 0,
headerOrgOffset = $('#centre').height();

$('header').height($('#centre').height());

$(window).scroll(function () {
var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
if (currentScroll > headerOrgOffset) {
    if (currentScroll > previousScroll) {
        $('header').fadeOut();
    } else {
        $('header').fadeIn();
    }
} else {
        $('header').fadeIn();
}
previousScroll = currentScroll;
});
</script>

<style type="css/text">
header {
width:100%;
height:86px;
background:#ffffff;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
position:fixed;
z-index: 1000;
display:block;
border-bottom: solid 1px #eee;
}

#centre {
width:960px;
height:86px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
background:#ffffff;
}
</style>

<header>
    <div id="centre">Nav</div>
</header>
```

Comment: I can't seem to replicate your problem with the code above. Could you please post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? A code fiddle such as JSFiddle or CodePen would really help too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a concept called debouncing. Any duplicate actions within a certain timeframe are basically ignored. In the following code, the `doSomething` method is only called 500ms after the last scroll event.

```
function doSomething() {
   // do some really cool stuff
}

var timer;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(doSomething, 500);
});
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for your answer. Do you also know how I can prevent the nav from disappearing immediately at the start of the page? So when it reaches something like 150px it disappears?

Comment: You will need to play around with that on your own as that's separate from this issue. Feel free to take a stab at it, and if you have problems create a JSfiddle and open an new question.